# Derive new fields that carry counts through for each record

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table full of outcomes from a chess tournament:

```
P1_id   P2_id   Outcome_for_P1  Day
1       2       W               2015-12-07
1       3       W               2015-12-06
1       4       D               2015-12-05
1       5       L               2015-12-04
1       6       D               2015-12-03
1       7       D               2015-12-02
1       8       L               2015-12-01
2       1       L               2015-12-07
2       3       W               2015-12-06
2       4       W               2015-12-05
2       5       W               2015-12-04
2       6       L               2015-12-03
2       7       D               2015-12-02
2       8       W               2015-12-01
```

This is great, but I've realized I need to derive 3 new columns. I'd like to track `P1_id`'s record throughout the tournament, as such:

```
P1_id    P2_id   Outcome_for_P1  P1_W  P1_L  P1_D  Day
1        2       W               2     2     3     2015-12-07
1        3       W               1     2     3     2015-12-06
1        4       D               0     2     3     2015-12-05
1        5       L               0     2     2     2015-12-04
1        6       D               0     1     2     2015-12-03
1        7       D               0     1     1     2015-12-02
1        8       L               0     1     0     2015-12-01
2        1       L               4     2     1     2015-12-07
2        3       W               4     1     1     2015-12-06
2        4       W               3     1     1     2015-12-05
2        5       W               2     1     1     2015-12-04
2        6       L               1     1     1     2015-12-03
2        7       D               1     0     1     2015-12-02
2        8       W               1     0     0     2015-12-01
```

Something like this is simple, but I don't know how to modify it so that it carries the count through

```
SELECT *, 
CASE Outcome_for_P1 when 'W' then 1
ELSE P1_W
END AS P1_W
FROM 
chess;
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to store in P1_W, P1_L and P1_D? Is it the wins, losses and draws for each game in the tournament?

Comment: Yes, it is P1's current record. As you can see, P1 lost the first game, so the 7th row (bottom row) shows this by counting a '1' in the column corresponding to the count of losses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
P1_id,
P2_id,
Outcome_for_P1,
P1_W,
P1_L,
P1_D,
Day
from (
 select c.*,
 @w:= if(@prev_p1 = P1_id, if(Outcome_for_P1 = 'W',@w+1,@w),if(Outcome_for_P1 = 'W',1,0)) as P1_W,
 @l:= if(@prev_p1 = P1_id, if(Outcome_for_P1 = 'L',@l+1,@l),if(Outcome_for_P1 = 'L',1,0)) as P1_L,
 @d:= if(@prev_p1 = P1_id, if(Outcome_for_P1 = 'D',@d+1,@d),if(Outcome_for_P1 = 'D',1,0)) as P1_D, 
 @prev_p1:= P1_id
 from chess c,(select @w:=0,@l:=0,@d:=0,@prev_p1:=0)x
 order by P1_id asc, Day asc
)x
order by P1_id asc, Day asc;
```

Comment: Aha! Like this! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/641efb/11
Works perfectly! If you would rewrite your answer using this SQL, I'd gratefully accept it.

Comment: Chakrabory...I was just thinking. How could this be modified so that  `P1_W`, 'P2_L', etc, show the player's record BEFORE the match? In other words, row 7 would hold `0` `0` `0` and row 6 would hold `0` `1` `0`, and so on? Would this be simple or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Yes you should ask a different question, since the logic needs to be re-defined.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on creating a new question...I went ahead and did it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533932/deriving-new-fields-that-show-a-value-dependent-on-the-prior-record-in-mysql

Comment: the ordering in the inner select must be `Day asc`.