# Deriving new fields that show a value dependent on the prior record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

*Please note: this question is an extension / modification of a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524806/derive-new-fields-that-carry-counts-through-for-each-record) that was expertly and graciously answered by 
@Abhik Chakraborty*

I have a MySQL table full of outcomes from a chess tournament:

```
P1_id   P2_id   Outcome_for_P1  Day
1       2       W               2015-12-07
1       3       W               2015-12-06
1       4       D               2015-12-05
1       5       L               2015-12-04
1       6       D               2015-12-03
1       7       D               2015-12-02
1       8       L               2015-12-01
2       1       L               2015-12-07
2       3       W               2015-12-06
2       4       W               2015-12-05
2       5       W               2015-12-04
2       6       L               2015-12-03
2       7       D               2015-12-02
2       8       W               2015-12-01
```

I've realized I need to derive 3 new columns. In my previous question, I  was trying to track P1_id's record throughout the tournament, by showing the outcome of the chess game that is represented by each row. This was as such:

```
P1_id    P2_id   Outcome_for_P1  P1_W  P1_L  P1_D  Day
1        2       W               2     2     3     2015-12-07
1        3       W               1     2     3     2015-12-06
1        4       D               0     2     3     2015-12-05
1        5       L               0     2     2     2015-12-04
1        6       D               0     1     2     2015-12-03
1        7       D               0     1     1     2015-12-02
1        8       L               0     1     0     2015-12-01
2        1       L               4     2     1     2015-12-07
2        3       W               4     1     1     2015-12-06
2        4       W               3     1     1     2015-12-05
2        5       W               2     1     1     2015-12-04
2        6       L               1     1     1     2015-12-03
2        7       D               1     0     1     2015-12-02
2        8       W               1     0     0     2015-12-01
```

This can be done using the code on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/641efb/8). Problem solved.

BUT I am having trouble modifying this SQL to populate the columns in a slightly different way. In this new situation, I'd like to show the competitor's Outcome *before* the conclusion of the game. It would show what the player's record was going into the chess match. In other words, how can I come up with this:

```
P1_id    P2_id   Outcome_for_P1  P1_W  P1_L  P1_D  Day
1        2       W               1     2     3     2015-12-07
1        3       W               0     2     3     2015-12-06
1        4       D               0     2     2     2015-12-05
1        5       L               0     1     2     2015-12-04
1        6       D               0     1     1     2015-12-03
1        7       D               0     1     0     2015-12-02
1        8       L               0     0     0     2015-12-01
2        1       L               4     1     1     2015-12-07
2        3       W               3     1     1     2015-12-06
2        4       W               2     1     1     2015-12-05
2        5       W               1     1     1     2015-12-04
2        6       L               1     0     1     2015-12-03
2        7       D               1     0     0     2015-12-02
2        8       W               0     0     0     2015-12-01
```

I'm struggling a bit because I don't think it can be done by the code on the Fiddle. I feel like a whole new approach might be necessary, but I'm not sure the best approach.

Comment: I can't exactly figure out the answer since I'm not familiar with your syntax (however I will submit a full answer if I figure it out), however I believe you can achieve what you want if you implement an unique id that increments by 1 with each match, then only add up stats for matches that have an ID less than the current one

Comment: ...I think I see what you are saying... :)

Comment: Thank you, I've made an answer that corresponds to my comment. If it is satisfactory please accept it as the answer, or you can wait until I figure out the actual SQL statement.

Comment: I am a patient person, I'll gladly wait so I can test your idea out in it's completion.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you can implement an unique id that increments by 1 with each match, then only add up stats for matches that have an ID less than the current one

Answer (score 0):

The sample from your fiddle-link doesn't work for me.
But here is an other solution: Join your matches with all previous matches from the same person and count the outcomes using `SUM`

```sql
SELECT c.P1_id, c.P2_id, c.Outcome_for_P1,
  SUM(IF(c1.Outcome_for_P1='W',1,0)) P1_W,
  SUM(IF(c1.Outcome_for_P1='L',1,0)) P1_L,
  SUM(IF(c1.Outcome_for_P1='D',1,0)) P1_D,
  c.Day
FROM chess c
LEFT JOIN chess c1
  ON  c1.P1_id = c.P1_id
  AND c1.Day   < c.Day
GROUP BY c.P1_id, c.P2_id, c.Outcome_for_P1, c.Day
ORDER BY c.P1_id ASC, c.Day DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/641efb/44